# Слово "невеста"

Tags: этимология

Какая этимология у слова "невеста"? Не от "не ведать" ли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По одной из версий - почти так. Только если уж совсем точно - "не ведомая". Как табуистическое "охранное" именование.

Другие версии приводить не хочется, за их сомнительностью.
А вообще очень много где есть. Даже в Вики:

http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0

Answer (score 2):

Невеста - не весть кто для семьи жениха. Особенно для свекрови:)

Answer (score 0):

Если бы я была поклонницей "народной этимологии", я бы сказала, что Веста - девственная богиня, которая невестой (не-Вестой) быть не может ;-) ))

Comment: А что? Вполне вероятно. По-чешски "бордель" - "невестинец". Сборище этих самых не-вест.